# Isekai manga where the main character wakes up as the Demon Lord

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember reading a manga where a kid wakes up inside of a game he used to play. He is a black-haired kid around the age of 13. He finds one of the characters standing by him, a female elf. I think He is considered a Demon Lord. A chapter later, a group of starving elves finds him, in their point of view, his face is a black smoke/scribble but they can see his body. They beg for help so he makes food out of thin air to feed their village. The first few chapters I've read, they were in the forest.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Kinda reminds me of Overlord, but he doesn't wakes up inside it, he stays there when the server are closing and finds himself stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for *Isekai Apocalypse MYNOGHRA ~The Conquest of the World Starts With the Civilization of Ruin~*

The main character is a black haired boy, named Ira Takuto. He wakes up in a forest in a new world after his death and sees Atou, a female elf hero from a game he played. At the end of the first chapter/beginning of the second, they are found by a group of dark elves who can only see Ira as a blurry, shadowy outline. After the dark elves tell the two about their problems, Ira uses some of his mana to create food for them.

There are some minor differences with the question:

- Atou tells Ira that this is not the game world she is familiar with, so this isn't the world of the game.
- Ira is called an "Evil Being" rather than specifically a "Demon Lord", at least in the translation I found.

Comment: I'm beginning to believe you were an otaku in another realm and got hit by a truck and transported to our world so you could become the undisputed *[King of Isekai ID-ing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiMHTK15Pik)*

Comment: I've just read a lot of Isekai.  Probably too much Isekai. It also helps that the site i read on lets me make a list of the ones i've read, which helps cut down on the search time if i can vaguely remember the title/cover if a question jogs my memory.

Comment: Looking at my stats, I've only done 20ish answers to Isekai questions. At least 20 that were tagged as such. though with only 62 question with that tag, that does seem to be a lot.